# Run Apps Script on a Sheet not in Current Workbook - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to be able to run a script in another spreadsheet outside of the current spreadsheet I am in.

I tried the below script but the script is not in the current spreadsheet editor

```
 function RunScriptInAnotherSpreadsheet() {

 var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");

//runs the below script
 relocationtomaster();

 }
```

am I dreaming ?

I understand a trigger would do that in the target sheet - just wanted to do it manually

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish the main script(with implementation of *relocationtomaster*) as [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). Then add this library as dependency to the script you want this code run.

Function *relocationtomaster* will be available in context of dependant script.

Example main script(publish as Library)

```
function relocationtomaster(id){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(id);

  Logger.log(ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues())

}
```

Example dependant script(include above script as library)

```
function run(){
  relocationtomaster('1MXsIX_SprLSimqNDUlDkEvWhtQp8Kz0By1IaA5JfkSA'); // Sheet id
}
```

You can pass spreadsheetid as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you have to publish them as a Library and call it from there, you can have a look here [how to run google app script function from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390885/how-to-run-google-app-script-function-from-another-project)

Mind that that id could affect to the performance of the script.